# ExtJS - Add listener to title

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a small `panel` with `title` and `body`.

```
var dashboardPanel1 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    collapsible: true,
    margin: '0 0 50 0',

    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        // The total column count must be specified here
        columns: 3
    },
    defaults: {
        // applied to each contained panel
        bodyStyle: 'padding:20px',
        border: 0
    },

    title: 'Key settings',

    items: [{
        html: '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/n7gOYrE.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px">',

    }, {
        html: '|Your key is active|',
    }, {
        html: '|Expiring date: 27.04.2018|',
    }],
});
```

How can I attach a listener to a `title`?

So, when I click on **Key settings**, it will be some action performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also trigger click event using `[Element.on()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-on)`.

> The [on](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-on) method is shorthand for [addListener](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.util.Observable.html#method-addListener). Appends an event handler to this object.

For example:

```
el.on("click", function(){
  //do something...
  //
}, this);
```

I this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2f9g)**, I have created a demo using your code and make some modification. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            collapsible: true,

            margin: '0 0 50 0',

            layout: {
                type: 'table',
                // The total column count must be specified here
                columns: 3
            },
            defaults: {
                // applied to each contained panel
                bodyStyle: 'padding:20px',
                border: 0
            },

            title: '<span class="mytitle">Key settings</span>',

            items: [{
                html: '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/n7gOYrE.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px">',

            }, {
                html: '|Your key is active|',
            }, {
                html: '|Expiring date: 27.04.2018|',
            }],

            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (panel) {
                    Ext.get(panel.el.query('span.mytitle')[0]).on('click', function (e) {
                        alert(e.target.innerText)
                    }, panel);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

Replace

```
title: 'Key settings',
```

with custom header:

```
header: {
    title: 'Custom header title',
    listeners: {
        click: function(h, e) {
            var tm = new Ext.util.TextMetrics(h);
            if (e.getX() < tm.getWidth('Custom header title')) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Information', 'Do some action!');
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Working example:**

```
var dashboardPanel1 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    collapsible: true,
    margin: '0 0 50 0',

    layout:
    {
        type: 'table',
        // The total column count must be specified here
        columns: 3
    },
    defaults:
    {
        // applied to each contained panel
        bodyStyle: 'padding:20px',
        border: 0
    },


    //title: 'Key settings',
    header: {
        title: 'Custom header title',
        listeners: {
            click: function(h, e) {
                var tm = new Ext.util.TextMetrics(h);
                if (e.getX() < tm.getWidth('Custom header title')) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Information', 'Do some action!');
                }   
            }
        }
    },

    items: [
    {
        html: '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/n7gOYrE.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px">',

    },
    {
        html: '|Your key is active|',
    },
    {
        html: '|Expiring date: 27.04.2018|',
    }],
});
```

**Notes:**

The example is tested with ExtJS 4.2. Title width is calculated with Ext.util.TextMetrics.

Comment: It affects the whole header. I want action to be performed when only text is clicked. In this case "Key settings".

Comment: @harunB10 I've made a small correction in example using getX() method. It's not perfect, but is working.

Comment: Now it's not working at all and I do not receive any error!

Comment: @harunB10 Strange, it works for me. Text 'Custom title header' is with almost 165 px width with my current resoltuion.